# I have a pipeline in Jenkins that have 14 stages, and I want to POST the duration, the result and the name of each stage into Graylog. How can I do?

Tags: jenkins, scripting, stage, graylog

I have a pipeline in Jenkins that have 14 stages, and I want to POST the duration, the result and the name of each stage into Graylog.
How can I do that in scripts?
I don´t know how to do that, and where and which variable names should I use.